# Mysql join query return duplicate row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT m.*
     , p.image_url
     , r.acceptance_status
  from playermessage m
  join playerprofile p
    on p.player_id = m.sender_id 
  join requesttempstorage r
    on r.requester_id = m.sender_id  
 where m.player_id = 48
```

This query is acting strange it gives me back two duplicate rows back but when I check the table playermessage there are no duplicate rows only this query would show the same message twice to a user while there is only one message can anybody spot the mistake.

---

```
| player_id | player_message                                          | date_sent           | sender_id | image_url          | acceptance_status |<br>
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------<br>------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------+<br>
|        48 | imran wants to be a part of the pakistan cricket team   | 2018-05-17 18:58:08 |        50 | uploads/imran.jpg  |                 1 |<br>
|        48 | fakhar wants to be a part of the pakistan cricket team  | 2018-05-17 19:13:27 |        51 | uploads/fakhar.jpg |                 1 |<br>
|        48 | shadab wants to be a part of the pakistan cricket team  | 2018-05-18 11:09:49 |        52 | uploads/shadab.jpg |                 1 |<br><strong>
|        48 | asif wants to be a part of the pakistan cricket team    | 2018-05-18 11:20:51 |        53 | uploads/asif.jpeg  |                 0 </strong>|<br>
<strong>|        48 | asif wants to be a part of the pakistan cricket team    | 2018-05-18 11:20:51 |        53 | uploads/asif.jpeg  |                 0 |</strong><br>
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------
```

The problem lies in the last two results(eg. ), It's returning two message when just all another message there is only one why is it doing it to last two results.

Comment: Without seeing the data in the tables it'll be difficult to assist.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: A select m.* should not return  .. duplicated  rows .. because you  should have a primary key in your table  .. so you should explain better your question  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these two queries is going to return two rows:

```
 SELECT p.* FROM playerprofile p WHERE p.player_id = 53
```

or

```
 SELECT r.* FROM requesttempstorage r WHERE r.requester_id = 53
```

---

The JOIN operation is finding *all* matching rows, and returning all of them.

If we have a row in `playermessage` with `sender_id = 53`, and

if there are *two* rows in `playerprofile` with `player_id = 53`, then we expect *two* rows to be returned.

If we had *three* rows in `playerprofile` with `player_id = 53`, then the join operation would return *three* rows.

If we have *zero* rows in `playerprofile` with `player_id = 53`, then we won't get any rows returned from `playermessage` with `sender_id = 53`.

---

If we also have two rows in `requesttempstorage` with `requester_id = 53`, that will also *double* the number of rows returned.

All of the columns from `playermessage` will be duplicated on each of those rows.

That's exactly how an inner join operation is designed to operate.